Forious Pull Down Kitchen Faucet Head Noisy / High Vibration
My in-laws have a Forious kitchen faucet that is making a ton of noise when water flows through the faucet head. I suspect that it needs a good internal cleaning. In taking this faucet head apart, I was able to get the buttons and strainers out...


But I cannot get the internal "guts" out. I suspect that the top needs to be screwed off, but I cannot seem to get the top piece off. You can see here that I am trying a bit too hard.

Any suggestions to get this apart?

What do you suspect is in there? Does it have reduced flow?

The strainers usually the first to collect stuff.  If the strainers are as clean as that faucet, you might be looking in the wrong spot.  Have you tried the faucet without the strainers on, or without the head on if possible(not soaking the ceiling)?

@isherwood not a reduced flow, there is a fair amount of vibration and it is extremely noisy. Like a dying velociraptor raptor.

@crip659 I have tried the faucet without the head on it and it is not noisy. I just tried to soak the head in vinegar overnight. I'll have to get back to their house to try it out again.

You can try soaking the entire unit in some vinegar, and hope that dissolves any calcification that may be causing your issue.  After that, try soaking it in bleach solution, in case the problem is also organic "gunk."
